# How to access tables in other schema in korma?

Tags: clojure, korma, sqlkorma

In SQL, accessing tables in other schema is simple:

```
select * 
from other_schema.t
where ...
```

How can I do this in korma? What I actually to do is to access `information_schema.tables` table. So defining another `db` by `defdb` wouldn't be helpful.

I've tried to define the entity, however, failed.

```
(defentity information_schema.tables)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got to know that there is a way to specify the base table when defining an entity. When specifying the base table, it allows to set the schema with `.`.

```
(defentity tables
  (table :information_schema.tables))
```

This works fine for accessing `information_schema.tables` table, without defining another db.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by defining another db.  I can create a db like this:

```sql
CREATE database my_db;
USE my_db;
CREATE TABLE stuff (
  things VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO stuff (things) VALUES ("some things");
```

Now I define two Korma databases and entities, and query them:

```lisp
(defdb my-db (mysql {:host "localhost" 
                     :port 3306 
                     :db "my_db"
                     :user "root"
                     :password nil}))

(defdb information-schema (mysql {:host "localhost" 
                                  :port 3306 
                                  :db "information_schema" 
                                  :user "root" 
                                  :password nil}))


(defentity stuff)

(defentity information-schema)

(select stuff
        (database my-db))

;; => ({:things "some things"})

(select TABLES 
        (database information-schema) 
        (fields :TABLE_SCHEMA :TABLE_NAME) 
        (where {:TABLE_SCHEMA "my_db"}))

;; => ({:TABLE_NAME "stuff", :TABLE_SCHEMA "my_db"})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Unfortunately, I don't know `root` users password, so I couldn't apply your suggestion. Anyway, I found the more suitable way. Please refer to my own answer.

Comment: You don't need the root user, each user will see results from `information_schema` for the objects they have access to, but i didn't want to confuse the example by adding in GRANT statements